# limit of sequence $U_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{an+1}{cn^{k}+j}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the limit of sequences of this general form:
$$
U_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{an+1}{cn^{k}+j}
$$

$$
k\in\Bbb{N}-\{0, 1\}
$$
$$
(a, b)\in\Bbb{R}^{+}_*\times\Bbb{R}^{+}_*
$$

Comment: Or at least the limit when $k=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a,c >0$, the function $\displaystyle f_n(x) = \frac{an+1}{cn^k+x}$ is decreasing in $[0, \infty)$, so

\begin{equation}
U_n \leq \int_0^n \frac{an+1}{cn^k+x} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty} U_n \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} (an+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{cn^{k-1}}\right)
\end{equation}

So for $k>2$ we have that $U_n \to 0$ if $n \to \infty$. If $k=2$ we get the upper bound of $a/c$. Now use the fact that

\begin{equation}
U_n \geq \int_1^{n+1} f_n(x) \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

to conclude that the limit is equal to $a/c$ if $k=2$.